# $\int_I f(x)u(x)=\int g(x)u(x)$ for $u$ that vanishes on the boundary, do $f$ and $g$ have to be equal?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have that $\int_I f(x)u(x)dx=\int_Ig(x)u(x)dx$ for all polynomials $u$. I know that if it were every $u$, then $f$ and $g$ are equal. But do they have to be equal in this case?

Comment: Almost everywhere, yes.

Comment: Thank you@Quoka Is this some theorem or where can I find a proof/some hints?

Comment: Presumably, $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a [compact?] interval, $u$ is continuous on $I$, and $f,g \in L^1(I)$.  Anything else?  (These assumptions need to be stated in the question... otherwise, you could be picking $u$ from a insufficiently rich set to be able to conclude $f=g$)

Comment: There is Lemma 27 in [https://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f13/dirichlet.pdf](this) document (we get $f-g=0$ a.e. so $f=g$ a.e.). There are probably a lot of sources, it's a well-known result. However, if this is for a class, then depending on what you have covered there are different approaches.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, and in the problem that I am thinking about, $I=(a,b)$, $u$ is a polynomial, and $f,g\in L^2$, if that's more information

Comment: @orangecat You should probably add that to your question. I assumed you meant any continuous function $u$ vanishing on the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling from what you've said in the question and comments, your most likely path to a proof is very simple:

1. Show (note) that $f_0(x) = f(x)(x-a)(x-b)$ defines a function $f_0 \in L^2(I)$ (similarly for $g_0(x) = g(x)(x-a)(x-b)$)
2. Let $v$ be an arbitrary polynomial on $(a,b)$ and show $\int_I f_0(x)v(x)\,dx = \int_I g_0(x)v(x)\,dx$.
3. Conclude $f_0=g_0$ (a.e.) and therefore $f=g$ (a.e.)

The "conclude" in step (3) is where all the heavy-lifting is done, but you have implied you already have this theorem, so just let that theorem do the heavy-lifting.